# C++ Задача с числовой прямой

Tags: c++, математика

При тестировании задачи в одном случае выдает ошибку.

> Задача: Дана числовая прямая. В переменной n количество точек на этой числовой прямой и сами точки. Каждая цифра, которая больше своих соседей на числовой прямой нам подходит. Вывести наименьшее положительное число из всех подходящих.
>
> **Ввод:**
>
> 5
>
> 4 5 2 3 1
>
> **Вывод:**
>
> 3

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int n, f[101], maz=1000000;
cin>>n;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
cin>>f[i];
}
for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
{
    if(f[j]!=0 && j<n)
    {
        if(f[j]>f[j-1] && f[j]>f[j+1])
        {
            if(f[j]<maz && f[j]>=0)
            {
            maz=f[j];
            }
        }
    }
}
if(maz!=1000000){cout<<maz<<endl;}else{cout<<"NO"<<endl;}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Первое и последнее число не подходят, так как их не с чем сравнивать. Я пробовал, ошибок только больше.

Comment: На каком случае падает? + с диапазоном цикловой переменной разберитесь.

Comment: @GreenDragon диапазон вроде не должен превышать n, иначе будет считывать больше чисел чем надо.

Comment: @GreenDragon в этом и проблема я не знаю с какими значениями программа падает. Компилятор при проверке сдачи программы выдает 2 ошибки из 10.

Comment: `if(f[j]>f[j-1] && f[j]>f[j+1])` что у вас там лежит при `j = 0` и `j = n-1` ?

Comment: @ничего, вверху же есть строчка if(f[j]!=0 && j<n), она не дает проверять j = 0

Comment: как именно? если вам `j==0` не нужен, инициализируйте с `j=1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так устроит?

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> v,p;
    copy_n(istream_iterator<int>(cin),n,
           back_inserter(v));
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i < v.size()-1; ++i)
        if (v[i] > v[i-1] && v[i] > v[i+1])
            p.push_back(v[i]);
    cout << *min_element(p.begin(),p.end()) << endl;
}
```

Comment: При вводе 5 проходит, но если ввести например 7 и цифры 1 5 -3 -2 -8 6 2, то должно по идее 5 вывести, а выводит -2.

Comment: но все равно спасибо, буду от этого отталкиваться

Comment: Позвольте, но -2 больше и -3, и -8!

Comment: извиняюсь это моя ошибка я написал в условии "наименьшее". Программа хорошо работает, спасибо за помощь!